# Why isn't /etc/hosts blocking domains after I add blocked sites via launchd?

Tags: osx, chrome, ipv6, hosts

I've been trying to setup Launchd to block several websites from Chrome on osX 10.12.2 from 9AM - 3PM Monday-Friday

I set up launchd to cp /etc/hosts_BLOCKED_sites.txt /etc/hosts

Launchd seems to be copying the file correctly.

$ ls -la /etc/hosts

```
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  619 Dec 29 09:00 /etc/hosts
```

$ sudo cat /etc/hosts

```
##  
# Host Database  
#  
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface  
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.  
##   
127.0.0.1   localhost   
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost  
::1             localhost   


# Blocked sites redirected to 0.0.0.0  
127.0.0.1 reddit.com  
127.0.0.1 www.reddit.com  
127.0.0.1 facebook.com  
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com   

# Block Facebook IPv6
fe80::1%lo0 facebook.com
fe80::1%lo0 reddit.com
::1 facebook.com
::1 www.facebook.com
::1 www.reddit.com  
::1 reddit.com
```

However, I can still open the blocked sites in Chrome browser after the /etc/hosts  are set to block access.

Any suggestions about why /etc/hosts isn't blocking access to the sites?

EDIT: 
Things I have attempted but have failed to block sites on Chrome:
**sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder** from the command line
I attempted to flush the Chrome DNS cache via chrome://net-internals/#dns
I attempted to flush the Chrome Sockets chrome://netinternals/#sockets

I also added the IPv6 format.
This did not make a difference. All the blocked sites are still accessible via Chrome v55.0.2883.95.

Comment: How are you testing that the sites are blocked? Are you blocking them just on the machine in question, or are you trying to block them on an entire network?  As you're just clobbering DNS for those hostnames, are you sure that the hostnames are not simply being cached in (e. g.) browsers?  Have you tried `dscacheutil -flushdns`? Why are you not using Macos' built-in parental controls to block web sites?

Comment: /etc/hosts should be 644 and not 600. You can also edit it directly, no need to involve launchd

Comment: I'm using launchd because I only want the site blocked from 9AM-3PM.
I'm testing that the sites are blocked by entering the URL in Chrome.

Comment: Please don't cross-post.

Comment: I wasn't sure if SuperUser was the best site to find the answers I was looking for. I didn't get any solutions that worked.

Answer (score 4):

Applications are not *required* to consult `/etc/hosts`. To get the desired effect, install and configure `dnsmasq`. See a snippet below from `dnsmasq.conf` that pertains to the goal.

```
# Add domains which you want to force to an IP address here.
# The example below send any host in double-click.net to a local
# web-server.
address=/local/0.0.0.0
address=/double-click.net/0.0.0.0
address=/google.com/0.0.0.0
address=/reddit.com/0.0.0.0  
address=/www.reddit.com/0.0.0.0
address=/facebook.com/0.0.0.0
address=/www.facebook.com/0.0.0.0
```

Then configure `/etc/resolv.conf` as follows.

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Also, redirect to `0.0.0.0` not `127.0.0.1`. It's much faster. The software, Unbound, can also achieve the same results. They both provide much, much more control over DNS and DHCP.

Comment: I have been using /etc/hosts in OS/X/MacOS for a few versions/years and it works pretty well to block sites.

Comment: Well, `/etc/hosts` is often a symlink, which makes Safari ignore it. Browsers can keep their own cache, etc. Firefox and Opera have both been known to completely ignore `/etc/hosts` - and multiple operating systems. Best to just bypass all issues and use "real" DNS, IMO.

Comment: Shucks. Won't work for the Ops's new requirement (9AM-3PM) though, without some wonky tinkering.

Comment: I use a mix of BIND rpz and hosts. In OSX hosts file is not a symlink

Comment: If it is a symlink, Safari ignores it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I realized it wasn't clear why I was using launchd.

I'm surprised how difficult for to figure out how to block domains. /etc/hosts used to work great.

Comment: `/etc/hosts` does work great. It's just that some software, most notably browsers (in my experience), do not always respect `/etc/hosts`, or they make name resolution appear dysfunctional because of the use of their own DNS cache, not the system cache. I think the answer will be in learning how to configure Chrome to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I attempted to flush the Chrome DNS cache via chrome://net-internals/#dns

I also attempted to flush the Chrome Sockets chrome://net-internals/#sockets      Neither worked.

Comment: I feel your pain. It's the reason I went to the DNS blackhole solution.

Comment: Is it possible to do this for specific sub-websites? e.g. a board on reddit or other website, of the form www.website.com/sub-website